# SQL Server I result logged in as Windows Authentication login even if I actually have logged in with another login

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

I created a simple database and I added a login mapped to a database user 'peter':

```
USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS HR;
GO

CREATE DATABASE HR;
GO

USE HR;

CREATE TABLE People (
  Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Country(
   cod int PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName)
  VALUES 
  ('John', 'Doe'),
  ('Jane', 'Doe'),
  ('Upton', 'Luis'),
  ('Dach', 'Keon');

USE [master];
CREATE LOGIN peter WITH PASSWORD='passwd123';


USE HR;

CREATE USER peter FOR LOGIN peter;

GRANT SELECT ON People TO peter;
```

Then if I log in with 'peter' I am also able to insert values into `Country` table (but also into `People`) despite I, as Peter, don't have any permission to do it.

**Running `SELECT system_user` always returns the WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION LOGIN even if I have logged in with 'peter' login**.

It seems to me that even if I have logged in as 'peter', for some strange reason I am always logged in as my WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION LOGIN.

I have logged in through SSMS Application using SQL Server Authentication for 'peter' login

Comment: the login usually allows sql authentification or windows (some more...) But i am unusre where you logon ssms Application?

Comment: @nbk Yes I have logged in through SSMS Application using SQL Server Authentication for 'peter' login

Comment: look under security which database roles peter has. that should clear things

Comment: @nbk Being logged in with WIndows Authentication login (which is a member of sysadmin server role)  I went to Security->Logins->peter->Right Click->Properties and in _Server Roles_ only _public_ is marked while in _User Mapping_ under the voice _Database role membership for:HR_  only _public_ is marked.

Comment: you could check also effective rights.

Comment: @nbk For some reason _Enforce pasword policy_  was marked for peter login. By simply unmarking it and reconnecting to the server using peter login , now `INSERT`  and all operations other than `SELECT` against `People` table (for which I grant select to peter) are denied as expected.  Could you explain me why?

Comment: Good to know make an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found there are two different conncetions in SSMS Application: the one under Object Explorer and the other is for query editor.

They are not synced : when I disconnect in in object explorer and reconnect with another login the query editor connection remains with the old login.